# PuTTY doesn't show oh-my-zsh prompt correctly

Tags: fonts, putty

When I use PuTTY to SSH into my Ubuntu server, it doesn't render the ➜ character in my prompt (default [oh-my-zsh](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh) prompt) correctly.

[image]

I tried using a [powerline](https://github.com/powerline/fonts) font, but it didn't change it. It looks like a spacing/aliasing issue, but I've tried changing all of the settings in PuTTY without any luck.

Any ideas?

Comment: Another option if @Koz's answer below doesn't solve it would be to use [ConEmu](https://conemu.github.io/) as a Windows terminal replacement and call [Win32-OpenSSH](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/wiki/Install-Win32-OpenSSH) from within ConEmu.

Answer (score 2):

The arrow glyph is cut off because the selected font is monospaced and the arrow is wider than the letters in your font.

In [Putty config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4vJM0.png), go to Window->Appearance and check the "Allow selection of variable-pitch fonts" box and try variable-width fonts such as Lucida Console. Putty actually seems to scale the glyphs to a fixed width rather than to allow variable-width characters.